# How to enable multiple concurrent windows remote desktop connections - W11

Tags: remote-desktop

Ive got a Windows Home 11 PC that i want to configure so that it allows multiple concurrent windows remote desktop users to connect.

Ive followed this guide [HERE](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/81353#:%7E:text=Enable%20Multiple%20RDP%20Sessions&text=Go%20to%20Computer%20Configuration%20%3E%20Administrative,Desktop%20Services%20session%20to%20Disabled.) but couldn't get it to work (although i not sure if that is a VMware specific guide)

Any ideas if this is possible and if so how can i do it ?

Comment: You need a terminal services license https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license

Comment: Thanks does the host computer need a windows server license or can it be a standard W11 home license ?

Comment: You can’t; Your use case cannot be accomplished on a Home license. I have serious doubts the group policy you changed is applicable to Home.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even see it said Home. So yeah, all bets are off.

Comment: @Ramhound ive actually just upgraded to W11 Pro as i needed some of those features will multiple concurrent remote desktop sessions work on W11 Pro instead ?

Comment: @sam - No; Terminal service licenses does not exist for Professional or Home editions of Windows. You cannot achieve what you want with Professional or Home.